# Hotmail contacts not syncing in android 5.1 GPE

Tags: sync, hotmail

I've just recently flashed my rom with Android GPE 5.1 on my HTC M7 and it's working great however there's a slight problem where for some reason my hotmail contacts are not syncing after I've set up my hotmail account in Gmail using exchange setup. On my old HTC M7 sense my hotmail accounts synced up and all appeared fine.

When I go to Accounts settings I can see my hotmail account is there under Gmail and I can see it shows Contacts, Calendars and Emails show as synced but only Calendars and Emails are indeed synced as I could see them in Gmail and my calendar app but I can't see any of my hotmail contacts.

I also tried installing outlook and adding my hotmail account but outlook is not appearing under the Account settings.

Anyone got a similar problem and know how to resolve this as I don't want to manually export and import my hotmail into google account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a clean wipe, set up my hotmail in Gmail as an exchange account. At first it didn't seem to work after a few updates I now see the contacts again.